# Powershell Getting Error Cannot convert value "System.Xml.XPathNodeList" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument

Tags: xml, powershell

I have following powershell code, which is selecting a xml node which has namespace.

```
$ns = new-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $doc.NameTable
$ns.AddNamespace("dns", "http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd")
$obj3 = $doc.SelectNodes('//dns:nlog',$ns)
```

But I am getting following error:

> Cannot convert value "System.Xml.XPathNodeList" to type
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be
>   inserted as  the valid child of this node, because the specified node
>   is the wrong type." At
>   C:\MetacubeAutoBuildDeployment\PowershellScripts\PEStandAloneWebConfigReplace.ps1:15
>   char:1
>   + $obj3 = $doc.SelectNodes('//dns:nlog',$ns)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Is there any specific reason for this error?
I Have to fetch the value of connectionString tag highlighted in the $doc.
$doc Contains:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <section name="ciel" type="Ciel.Application.Common.CielConfigSectionHandler, Ciel.Application" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.FallbackErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah.FallbackErrorLog" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- Load NLog extensions from the *.dll file -->
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Web" />
      <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
    </extensions>
    <!-- Targets or Output -->
    <targets>
      <default-wrapper xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" />
      <!-- File Target -->
      <target name="sqllog" xsi:type="File" fileName="App_Data/NLoggerLogs/PESql.log" archiveFileName="App_Data/log/CielSql.{#####}.log" maxArchiveFiles="100" archiveAboveSize="10485760" archiveNumbering="Sequence" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false" encoding="UTF-8">
        <layout xsi:type="CSVLayout" delimiter="Tab">
          <column name="level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
          <column name="aspnet-sessionid" layout="${aspnet-sessionid}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(ASP.NET_SessionId)" layout="${aspnet-request:cookie=ASP.NET_SessionId}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(HTTP_USER_AGENT)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_USER_AGENT}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(REMOTE_ADDR)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(REMOTE_HOST)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_HOST}" />
          <column name="date" layout="${longdate}" />
          <column name="message" layout="${message:exceptionSeparator=|:withException=true}" />
          <column name="aspnet-user-identity" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
        </layout>
      </target>
      <target name="debuglog" xsi:type="File" fileName="App_Data/NLoggerLogs/PE.log" archiveFileName="App_Data/log/Ciel.{#####}.log" maxArchiveFiles="100" archiveAboveSize="2097152" archiveNumbering="Sequence" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false" encoding="UTF-8">
        <layout xsi:type="CSVLayout" delimiter="Tab">
          <column name="date" layout="${longdate}" />
          <column name="level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
          <column name="asp-application" layout="${asp-application}" />
          <column name="asp-request" layout="${asp-request:cookie=String:serverVariable=String:queryString=String:item=String:form=String}" />
          <column name="asp-session" layout="${asp-session:variable=String}" />
          <column name="aspnet-sessionid" layout="${aspnet-sessionid}" />
          <column name="aspnet-session" layout="${aspnet-session:variable=Sring}" />
          <column name="aspnet-application" layout="${aspnet-application:variable=String}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request" layout="${aspnet-request:cookie=String:serverVariable=String:queryString=String:item=String:form=String}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(ASP.NET_SessionId)" layout="${aspnet-request:cookie=ASP.NET_SessionId}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(HTTP_USER_AGENT)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_USER_AGENT}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(URL)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=URL}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(REMOTE_ADDR)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(REMOTE_HOST)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_HOST}" />
          <column name="aspnet-user-authtype" layout="${aspnet-user-authtype}" />
          <column name="aspnet-user-identity" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
          <column name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
          <column name="stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace:topFrames=2}" />
          <column name="machinename" layout="${machinename}" />
          <column name="document-uri" layout="${document-uri}" />
          <column name="callsite" layout="${callsite:className=true:fileName=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true}" />
          <column name="message" layout="${message:exceptionSeparator=|:withException=true}" />
        </layout>
      </target>
      <target name="accesslog" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/APP_Data/NLoggerLogs/PEAccess.log" archiveFileName="${basedir}/App_Data/log/CielAccess.{#####}.log" maxArchiveFiles="100" archiveAboveSize="2097152" archiveNumbering="Sequence" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false" encoding="UTF-8">
        <layout xsi:type="CSVLayout" delimiter="Tab">
          <column name="aspnet-sessionid" layout="${aspnet-sessionid}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(HTTP_USER_AGENT)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_USER_AGENT}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(REMOTE_ADDR)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}" />
          <column name="aspnet-request(REMOTE_HOST)" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_HOST}" />
          <column name="date" layout="${longdate}" />
          <column name="message" layout="${message:exceptionSeparator=|:withException=true}" />
        </layout>
      </target>
      <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
        <!--
        Remarks:
          The appsetting layouts require the NLog.Extended assembly.
          The aspnet-* layouts require the NLog.Web assembly.
          The Application value is determined by an AppName appSetting in Web.config.
          The "NLogDb" connection string determines the database that NLog write to.
          The create dbo.Log script in the comment below must be manually executed.
        -->
        <!--<connectionStringName>SQLServer_develop</connectionStringName>-->
        <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
        **<connectionString>server=server;database=database;integrated security=False;User ID=userid;Password=password</connectionString>**
        <commandText>
          insert into [CIEL].[DPR_JOBINSTANCEDETAILS] (
          JOBID, JOBINSTANCEID, STEPINSTANCEID,STEPID,LOGTYPE, MESSAGETYPE, MESSAGE, PARENTID,LOGGEDON
          )
          values (
          @JOBID, @JOBINSTANCEID, @STEPINSTANCEID, @STEPID, @LOGTYPE,@MESSAGETYPE, @MESSAGE, @PARENTID, @LOGGEDON
          );
        </commandText>
        <parameter name="@JOBID" layout="${event-properties:item=JOBID}" />
        <parameter name="@JOBINSTANCEID" layout="${event-properties:item=JOBINSTANCEID}" />
        <parameter name="@STEPINSTANCEID" layout="${event-properties:item=STEPINSTANCEID}" />
        <parameter name="@STEPID" layout="${event-properties:item=STEPID}" />
        <parameter name="@LOGTYPE" layout="${event-properties:item=LOGTYPE}" />
        <parameter name="@MESSAGETYPE" layout="${event-properties:item=MESSAGETYPE}" />
        <parameter name="@MESSAGE" layout="${event-properties:item=MESSAGE}" />
        <parameter name="@PARENTID" layout="${event-properties:item=PARENTID}" />
        <parameter name="@LOGGEDON" layout="${date}" />
      </target>
      <target name="sqllog_table" xsi:type="Database">
        <!--Remarks:
          The appsetting layouts require the NLog.Extended assembly.
          The aspnet-* layouts require the NLog.Web assembly.
          The Application value is determined by an AppName appSetting in Web.config.
          The "NLogDb" connection string determines the database that NLog write to.
          The create dbo.Log script in the comment below must be manually executed.-->
        <connectionStringName>NLogConnection</connectionStringName>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <!-- Rules for calling the appropriate Target -->
    <rules>
      <logger name="DebugLogger" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debuglog" />
      <logger name="SqlLogger" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="sqllog" />
      <logger name="AccessLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="accesslog" />
      <logger name="PROCESSENGINEDB" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post more code detailing what `$doc` contains.

Comment: I would simply use `$xml.GetElementsByTagName('connectionString')[0].'#text'`

Comment: I apologize that I have posted partial xml file here, because other part contains some information that I cannot share. There are other tags with connectionString and other xml sections which contains name spaces, so this xml contains multiple namespaces. Because of that I have to pass namespace in the powershell. Thank you so much for posting the answers.

Comment: @gms0ulman, your code did the work for me. But this is done with the absolute path. Can it be done using relative? if there is no option then I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta I've edited my answer to add `GetElementsByTagName` based it being called "target", with a step to filter where name is "database". Now that you have both methods, it's up to you to decide which one (or which combination)  is more suitable based on your data, and how this might change over time.

Comment: Another approach: `$xml.SelectNodes('//*[local-name()="target" and @name="database"]/*[local-name()="connectionString"]').'#text'` - note that StackOverflow mangles the code in comments so copypasting from here might not work.

Comment: Thanks gms0ulman and wOxxOm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GetElementsByTagName` as suggested by [WOxxOm's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919466/powershell-getting-error-cannot-convert-value-system-xml-xpathnodelist-to-type?noredirect=1#comment76827240_44919466). It's elegant. But potential issues could be caused by changing xml structure, re-ordering or multiple connectionStrings.

You could dot-index into the XML. The advantage is that it is more explicit. The disadvantage is that it is more explicit.

If you change the path to the connectionString this will need to be updated where as `GetElementsByTagName` will not. However this is better for explicitly defining the tag you are interesting in and to give you convenient access to the other pieces of information within that tag. I find it is generally more intuitive.

```
$dbdetails = $doc.configuration.nlog.targets.target | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "database"}
$dbdetails.ConnectionString
```

Your code did not give me the same error on PowerShell v5.1. I copied your code for $doc, assigning it to a variable using a here-string:

```
[xml]$doc = @"
    ...
"@
```

---

**Edit:**

Best of both worlds?

```
$dbdetails = $doc.GetElementsByTagName("target") | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "database"}
```

---

**Get-Member**, showing the accessible properties

[image: Get-Member n $dbdetails]